# In what cases would I want to use inline assembly code in C/C++ code

Tags: c++, c, assembly, inline-assembly

I just read that assembly code can be included directly in C/C++ programs, like,

```
__asm statement
__asm {
statement-1
statement-2
...
statement-n
}
```

I'm just wondering in what cases would it be useful to include assembly code in C/C++.

Comment: Plain simply, practically nowhere.

Comment: Don’t get me wrong but why would you want to do that ? It decreases the readability a lot and good code is all about readability.

Comment: Back in the old days, humans could write faster, more compact assembly than some of the compilers. So when the compilers didn't do a good job, the human would resort to inline assembly to get the job done. Nowadays, assembly code is so advanced (i.e. complicated and convoluted), and the compilers are so good, that it's rare that there's justification for inline assembly.

Comment: It's also not portable even on the same architecture (For example, x86-64 MSVC doesn't even support inline assembly, and 32 bit inline assembly on MSVC is very different in syntax from, say, gcc).

Comment: What *can* be useful on x86 platforms is SSE/AVX/etc. intrinsic functions, most of which map one to one to instructions, but unlike inline assembly, are actually understood by the compiler and be subject to optimizations, its register allocation algorithms, etc.

Comment: If it was not useful, I don't think this feature would've been provided in first place. I just want to know if there are any other reasons like @user3386109 mentioned. One more question I have is whether this facility is supported now in any C++ compilers or not, if yes, is this just to support the legacy system.

Comment: @Shawn, i didn't get what you are referring to, can you please elaborate more or mention any references that could help me better understand what you said.

Comment: tl;dr: Don't use inline assembly.

Comment: @pasha: there weren't always good intrinsics (`#include <immintrin.h>`), or good compiler support for optimizing them.  There *are* intrinsics / builtins for basically everything now in MSVC, so much so that inline asm support could be dropped for x86-64 even though MS still (I assume) uses MSVC to build the Windows kernel.

Comment: You would use it when you want to force specific instructions to be used.  There are many cases where this is useful, but you weight the pros and the cons of this approach (vs real assembly, vs tolerate the compilers results)

Comment: @user3386109 it is easy to find optimization points in todays compilers for any decent/real sized project there are many places you can improve the result.  GCC for example has gone backward in the quality of its output the last few major versions.  compilers do an okay average job, and are consistent, some humans can match or outperform them but it is more work (typing) to complete so the preference is to let the compiler do its then then tune where needed (with good justification, which is definitely rare).  But inline adds even more work and should be used even less often if ever.

Comment: @pasha there are use cases, but negatives, inline asm specifically is not part of the language proper but compiler implementation specific so by definition not portable, you are messing with the compilers ability to do its job so inline is messy and has lots of rules so that the compiler doesnt break.  real asm assembled and linked is cleaner for most if not all of the use cases where you might consider inline asm.  There are use cases for asm though and as a result there are compilers that will attempt to support it

Comment: As well as the answer below about embedded systems where you want to control/force the instruction.  Often also in embedded systems, the compiler doesnt know the system it knows the processor and has assumptions, so it cant know the performance of ram vs instruction execution/fetches, so there are times where the same solution is much slower on one platform and another is better, so for folks on that platform there would be a desire either through a compiler optimizer option or by directly fixing the code through real or inline asm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most significant place (and probably only one where it makes sense) where assembly use in C/C++ is used is in embedded systems development, where it is the only way to access some peripherals or where it is required to do so because we need this exact order of instructions no matter what the compilation flags are. This last case is most often seen in bootloaders or critical OS parts like the context switch.

The example that comes to mind is accessing the special registers in a MicroBlaze processor: even [Xilinx recommends accessing those registers using assembly](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/17026.html) (there is also no other way that I know of) **because there is no other way**.

By embedding it in C, it would be used like this:

```c
unsigned long get_msr(void) {
    unsigned long msr; 
    asm ("mfs %0, rmsr" : "=d" (msr)); // note: this is a gnu extention
    return msr;
}
```

Another example is the [implementation for a context switch](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0471c/Cjaebbeh.html) provided by ARM also uses assembly (although not embedded in C code in this case).

Comment: That's GNU C inline asm, where you can write input / output constraints to tell the compiler which registers are inputs and outputs.  The OP is asking about MSVC inline asm, which is so bad that MSVC dropped it for x64 (brittle implementation in MSVC, and inefficient syntax).  The could do this because they have intrinsics for most things that you'd use GNU C inline asm for, even stuff like x86 `cli` / `sti` to disable / enable interrupts in kernel code.